# posixAccounts API information missing

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I'm not seeing my posixAccounts information from the following link:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/get

```
{
  "kind": "admin#directory#user",
  "id": "8675309",
  "etag": "\"UUID\"",
  "primaryEmail": "email@example.com",
  "name": {
    "givenName": "Email",
    "familyName": "Account",
    "fullName": "Email Account"
  },
  "isAdmin": true,
  "isDelegatedAdmin": false,
  "lastLoginTime": "2021-08-04T21:11:17.000Z",
  "creationTime": "2021-06-16T14:32:35.000Z",
  "agreedToTerms": true,
  "suspended": false,
  "archived": false,
  "changePasswordAtNextLogin": false,
  "ipWhitelisted": false,
  "emails": [
    {
      "address": "email@example.com",
      "primary": true
    },
    {
      "address": "email@example.com.test-google-a.com"
    }
  ],
  "phones": [
    {
      "value": "123-456-7890",
      "type": "work"
    }
  ],
  "nonEditableAliases": [
    "email@example.com.test-google-a.com"
  ],
  "customerId": "id12345",
  "orgUnitPath": "/path/to/org",
  "isMailboxSetup": true,
  "isEnrolledIn2Sv": false,
  "isEnforcedIn2Sv": false,
  "includeInGlobalAddressList": true
}
```

As you can see from the above output, there's no posixAccount information.  I can open the ldap information in Apache Directory studio, so I know it's there, but I can't see it from the above output.  Since I can see it though, I tried to update this using the update function in the API.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/update

I used this for the payload as I'm just testing updating the gid information.  I used the documentation below to get the entry details needed.  At least as far as I could tell.

```
{
  "posixAccounts": [
    {
      "gid": "12345",
    }
  ]
}
```

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users

I'm getting a 200 response, but nothing is actually changing for the user when doing a PUT to update.

I tried a similar update method from another user on here, but no avail: [Google Admin SDK - Create posix attributes on existing user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51692019/google-admin-sdk-create-posix-attributes-on-existing-user)

Comment: Can you add in some reproduction steps to your question? Its hard to know whats wrong without knowing exactly what you are doing or how you have set it up.

Comment: Understood.  I've made an update with additional details.  Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this resolved by supplying additional details in my PUT request:

```
{
  "posixAccounts": [
    {
      "username": "email(excluding @domain.com)",
      "uid": "1234",
      "gid": "12345",
      "operatingSystemType": "unspecified",
      "shell": "/bin/bash",
      "gecos": "Firstname Lastname"
      "systemId": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

The above wouldn't reflect in LDAP until I put "systemId" in there.  So that part is required.